# Why does my CSS render incorrectly on mobile?

Tags: css, google-chrome, mobile, flexbox, webkit

I'm using chrome both on my laptop and on my iphone.

I created a simple example that demonstrates the problem:  https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/asteroid-public/test/test.html

Try viewing that page on your desktop/laptop. The messages render correctly, not overlapping each other.  Even when you use the DevTools to view the page as if you are viewing on a mobile device, it still works fine on the laptop.  Now, try viewing it on your chrome app on your mobile phone.  The messages all overlap each other and so it is hard to read.

Here are some screenshots showing the difference:

[image: How it looks on laptop]
[image: How it looks on mobile]

Why is this happening and how do I fix it on mobile?

Comment: what  `font-size` did you use? you need make the font-size responsive too, with `rem` or `em`

Comment: font-size is not the issue.  The messages should not overlap regardless of the font size.

Comment: what browser did you use?  im testing with chrome dev tools phone toolbar and it doesn't happen

Comment: right, it always works correctly for me when using dev tools. It's when you use the actual google chrome app on the iphone that it breaks.

Comment: add -webkit-flex to all compatiblity with chrome

Comment: the CSS is  `-webkit-box-flex` and `-webkit-box-direction` that values use and test

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your .chat .message css properties are causing this. I understand what you tried to do by doing this:

```
     .chat .message {
       margin: 4px 16px;
       white-space: nowrap;
       display: flex;
       flex-direction: row;
       align-items: center;
       position: relative;
       }
```

However what is causing your problem seems to be the display property. I hope that helps.

```
.chat .message {
       margin: 4px 16px;
       white-space: nowrap;
       //display: flex;
       //flex-direction: row;
       align-items: center;
       position: relative;
       }
```

Comment: You're right, it works now.  Why do you think that was breaking it?

Answer (score -1):

I suggest making all `div class="message"` include a `div class="inner"`. In this way, you can have your `div class="inner"` at a `width: 80%;` and `display: block;`, and your messages have `width: 100%;` and `height: auto;`. You can set alignment rules on `div class="message"` by using `.message[origin-me]` and `.message[origin-them]` to set where the `div class="inner"` aligns. I hope this helps!